# Condtion ngIf on date

Tags: angular

I have a div that i want to append an ngIf condition on date.

At the moment i'm displaying all the dates like this:

```
<div class="user" *ngFor="let user of user">
        <div *ngIf="user.recipient === selectedUser._id && showUser(User)">
          <div *ngIf="shouldDisplayDate(user.date)">
          <div class="message-date">{{ user.date | date:'EEEE'}} {{user.date | date:'d'}}  {{ user.date | date:'MMMM'}} {{ user.date |
            date:'yyyy'}}
          </div>
          </div>
```

As Example :

```
["Mon Jul 16 2018 11:40:28 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:33:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:21:36 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:03:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:01:05 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 08:53:23 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 08:52:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:49 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)"]
```

I have 6 Times Fri 13 Jul + 3 Times Thu 12 July and one time Mon 16 Jul

I want to only display the first one of every date and not all of them

```
"Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
"Mon Jul 16 2018 11:40:28 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:33:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
```

the ts

```
messageRed(date: Date) {
    const users = this.messages.map(a => a.date);
    for (const dateString of users) {
      if (!this.datesFiltered.find(d => new Date(d).setHours(0, 0, 0) == new Date(dateString).setHours(0, 0, 0))) {
        this.datesFiltered.push(new Date(dateString))
        console.log(this.datesFiltered) // this will display the filtred data
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to do an ngIf on date ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: At the moment i display all of the date, didn't figure out how to set the condition so i can only display the most recent date only once

Answer (score 1):

I work on first version of want you want:

https://angular-pyzt3g.stackblitz.io

I filter data by unique values(year-month-day), the rest is filter the uniques with the last date of unique year-month-day.

cheers!

Comment: Thank you sir for you message, i'm fetching the data from an array of object in a mongo Database, the date is in ISODATE

Comment: JavaScript's Date object supports the ISO date format. Just new Date(your ISODATE).

Comment: Sir is there a way to wrap it on a function and not in the constructor ?

Comment: didnt know ur model data, where u have the array of dates? if u dont do a runnable example or inform us about ur model data we cant help you.

Comment: Sir please check my updated question, i implemented your method, is there a way to do an ngIf with the index ?

Comment: you can *ngIf="uniqueKeys[index]". But your really problem is your implementation is incorrect i think, but i cant help you more if i havent all data structure and real context of problem.

Answer (score 1):

I will rather to push all the unique dates somehwere else. To Implement a logic to filter and get the unique dates on user selection change or elsewhere your component change it's user state. 
Something like that:

```
   //Clear the uniqueDate collection first
   this.uniqueDates=[];
   // Get all the filtered user dates
   const dates = users.filter(user => user.recipient === this.selectedUser._id && this.showUser(User))
                      .map(uniqueDates=> filteredUsers.date);

    const uniqueKeys: { [name: string]: any; } = {};
    // Unique dates
    dates.forEach((element) => {
       const uniquieKey = element.getDate() + element.getMonth() + element.getFullYear();
       if (!uniqueKeys[uniquieKey]) {
          uniqueKeys[uniquieKey] = element;
          this.uniqueDates.push(element);
        } 
     });
   }
 }
```

This will remove the if conditions in the template and make it more readable.

```
<div class="user" *ngFor="let date of uniqueDates">       
          <div class="message-date">{{ date | date:'EEEE'}} {{date | date:'d'}}  {{ date | date:'MMMM'}} {{ date |
            date:'yyyy'}}
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir i'm getting ERROR TypeError: element.getDate is not a function

Comment: user.date is probably not Date type. Try to change your map function ->  .map(filteredUsers=> new Date(filteredUsers.date));

Comment: Sir i tried to follow your solution still get all the dates

Comment: Thank you sir, edited it like you told, now it's displaying nothing :/  is there a way to do a function and to call it an an ngIf ?

Comment: The idea here is not to use ifs but to build the collection in the logic behind the template. To give you this answer I used static data, but your task is more complex than that and I'm not aware of what is happening there. Probably you collect the data asynchronous and it's not there yet, don't know. My advice for you is  to put a little effort in solving the problem. Do not jump from one solution to another just to make it run. The future you will be thankful for that. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You could put something like this in the code of your component:

```
lastDate: Date = null;

shouldDisplayDate(date: Date) : boolean {
    if (date != this.lastDate) {
        this.lastDate = date;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then in the template:

```
<div *ngIf="shouldDisplayDate(user.date)">
    <div class="user-date">{{ user.date | date:'EEEE'}} {{user.date | date:'d'}}  {{ user.date | date:'MMMM'}} {{ user.date |date:'yyyy'}}</div>
</div>
```

The result should be what you want, if I understood correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment i got this error message :
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.

Comment: I want to get ride of "redundant" Date by displaying only the most recent one, if i get 15 date the same date i only want to display the most recent date of that day

Comment: You may have a structure problem in your component and should probably read https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Comment: the function i gave should be easy enough to adapt to that requirement, but i'd need the entire page and model to figure out an exact solution.

Comment: I get this message when i have only one date, but when i have multiple date nothing happening, i'm getting all the date

Comment: i edited my question, so i get all the users from the database.